# Json data in chartjs multiple line

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I would like to display my json data in  multiple (3) lines chartjs by using a c# application, it's possible to use the following json file format to do that ?
Labels are the years.
Thanks.

```
[
 [
 "2013",
 "2013",
 "2013",
 "2014",
 "2014",
 "2014"
 ],
 [
 "City1",
 "City2",
 "City3",
 "City1",
 "City2",
 "City3"
 ],
 [
 "151",
 "2536",
 "363",
 "5074",
 "2182",
 "369"
 ]
]
```